# Javascript, simple: make global

Tags: javascript, regex, global

Here is a simple regex expression...

```
document.getElementById('testing').value=f2.innerHTML.replace(">",">\n");
```

The problem is it stops after the first linebreak, how can I make it do the whole table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.replace(/>/g, ">\n");`.

RegEx literal (or at least that's what I call it) uses two `/`'s. One to mark the begninning, one to mark the end. If you need to use an actual / in the replacement, you'll have to escape the / with a backslash (\). For example: `/Hi\/Hello/`.

With RegEx literals, modifiers come after the last `/`. In the case above, "g" means global and will replace all, not just the first one it comes to.

Comment: Thanks! But if I want to match a tag, for example <table> then what? Esp if table has attributes like border etc... basically start match `"<table"` and end with `">"`

Comment: ` "g" means global and will replace all, not just the first one it comes to.` I realized that, but I had quotes around around the search like this "/>"/g and of course that did not work...